# Pencil drawing and finger gesture unable to be recognized simultaneously SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, pencilkit, apple-pencil

in a project we are working on using `SwiftUI` and `PencilKit` we are required to create a button that while being tapped, changes the `PKInkingTool` of the `PKCanvasView` we are using.

`PencilKit` uses `UIKit` so we have it enclosed in a `UIViewRepresentable` this way:

#### CanvasView

```swift
import PencilKit
import SwiftUI

struct CanvasView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var canvas = PKCanvasView()

    private var pen = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .black , width: 2)
    private var eraser = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .white , width: 2)
    private var marker = PKInkingTool(.marker, color: .white , width: 2)
    private var corrector = PKInkingTool(.marker, color: .white , width: 2)
    private var currentTool: PKInkingTool
    private var width: CGFloat = 2
    
    
    init() {
        self.currentTool = pen
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        canvas.drawingGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        canvas.tool = pen
        return canvas
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    
    mutating func setPen(color: Color) {
        pen.color = color.uiColor()
        pen.width = width
        currentTool = pen
        canvas.tool = currentTool
    }
    
    mutating func setCorrector(color: Color) {
        corrector.color = color.uiColor()
        corrector.width = width
        currentTool = corrector
        canvas.tool = currentTool
    }
    
    mutating func setMarker(color: Color) {
        marker.color = color.uiColor()
        marker.width = width
        currentTool = marker
        canvas.tool = marker
    }
    
    mutating func setWidth(width: CGFloat) {
        self.width = width
        currentTool.width = width
        canvas.tool = currentTool
    }
    
    mutating func setEraser(width: CGFloat) {
        eraser.width = width
        canvas.tool = eraser
    }
    
    func setLasso(){
        canvas.tool = PKLassoTool()
    }
    
    func setMagicButtonTool(tool: PKInkingTool) {
        var newTool = tool
        newTool.width = width
        canvas.tool = newTool
    }
    
    func restoreTool() {
        canvas.tool = currentTool
    }
    
}
```

The button that changes the `PKInkingTool` **only** while is being tapped is as follows:

#### MagicButtonView

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MagicButtonView: View {
    
    // MARK: - View objects
    @Environment(\.mainWindowSize) private var mainWindowSize
    
    // MARK: - Public properties
    var icon: Image
    var color: Color
    var action: (_ isTapped: Bool) -> Void
    
    @State var isTapped: Bool = false
    // MARK: - View body
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image.iconNotesPencil
                .resizable()
                .padding(.all, 18)
        }
        .background(Circle()
            .foregroundColor(color)
            .frame(
                width:  mainWindowSize.proportionalWidth(with: .widthSizeRatio),
                height: mainWindowSize.proportionalHeight(with: .heightSizeRatio))
                .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(
                            Color.colorBackgroundGray,
                            lineWidth: 2
                        )
                )
        )
        .frame(
            width:  mainWindowSize.proportionalWidth(with: .widthSizeRatio),
            height: mainWindowSize.proportionalHeight(with: .heightSizeRatio))
        .gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.01)
                .onChanged({ _ in
                    if !isTapped {
                        isTapped = true
                        action(isTapped)
                    }
                })
                .onEnded({ _ in
                    isTapped = false
                    action(isTapped)
                })
        )
    }
}
```

And would be implemented in the parent view as:

```swift
MagicButtonView(icon: .iconNotesPencil, color: .red, action: { isTapped in
            if isTapped {
                canvas.setMagicButtonTool(
                    tool: PKInkingTool(
                        .pen,
                        color: .red,
                        width: 2
                    )
                )
            } else {
                canvas.restoreTool()
            }
        }),
```

#### The Problem

When we tap on the `MagicButtonView` , then `CanvasView` is unresponsive and won't register any `UIGestureRecognizer` event, and viceversa, when we are using `CanvasView` the `MagicButtonView` becomes unresponsive and won't register any `SwiftUI.Gesture`

#### What could be it?

Maybe its because its a mix of `SwiftUI` and `UIKit` views, we learn in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64631062/touches-gestures-in-swiftui-and-uiviewcontrollerrepresentable-arent-recognise) but we are note sure is that since in that question the problem is not with `PencilKit`

Another thing we thought is incompatibility with hand gestures and the Apple Pencil being on the screen due to palm rejection, but in other apps like GoodNotes, you can still change i.e. the color of the pencil while drawing, only that the change won’t be effective until you release the pencil of the screen and start drawing again, but that would be okay to us.

#### What have we tried?

We made a lot of combinations and try-outs, we changed `MagicButtonView` `.gesture()` to `.highPriorityGesture()` and also `.simultaneousGesture()` and no luck.

We also changed `CanvasView` `canvas.drawingPolicy` using `.anyInput`, `.pencilOnly` and `.default` with no results.

We also tried `canvas.drawingGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = **false**` and fail.

We moved `MagicBottonView` to a higher parent view so it’s not in the same as `CanvasView` also with no results.

We also used other gestures than `DragGesture()` in `MagicButtonView` but `DragGesture()` is the only one that don't time out and can register got a longer time than `LongPressGesture`